# Get Minutes between two hours given in SQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Get Minutes between two hours given in SQL stored procedure.

```
I am having start time : 07:00:00.0000000
I am having end time hour:15:00:00.0000000
I just want minute between these both.
```

This I want for the SQL stored procedure.

```
SELECT @Minutes= Datediff(Minute, CONVERT(TIME, @StartTime), CONVERT(TIME, @EndTime))
```

It is giving me negative integer if start time is 23 to 7. For that what to do? It is like shift time. for an example : 23 on 1st June to 7oclock morning on 2nd June.

Comment: please show us some code snippets to better help you. The SO community will not do your entire project.

Comment: It is giving me negative integer if start time is 23 to 7. for that what to do? It is like shift time. for an example : 23 on 1st june to 7oclock morning on 2nd june.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE TIME = '07:00:00.0000000'
DECLARE @ENDDATE TIME = '15:00:00.0000000'

SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @STARTDATE,@ENDDATE)
```

Updated:

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME='2014-06-23 23:00:00'
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME = '2014-06-24 07:00:00'

SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @STARTDATE,@ENDDATE)
```

Comment: It is giving me negative integer if start time is 23 to 7. for that what to do? It is like shift time. for an example : 23 on 1st june to 7oclock morning on 2nd june.

Comment: Declare variables "DATETIME" type. Ex: DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME='2014-06-23 23:00:00'

Comment: can you write whole query

Comment: i have already updated on mu post. Please see the Query below the "Updated:" tag

Comment: 2016-10-23 20:44:11.000 and 2016-10-22 20:44:11.000 these dates are not giving output. it is giving me output as NULL.

Comment: It return 1440 and this is right. Please check it carefully

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`DateDiff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189794.aspx)** Function to find the difference in `minutes`. The problem is since we are didn't mention the date it took the minute difference between next date.

```
Declare @StartTime datetime='2014-06-01 23:00:00',
        @EndTime   datetime='2014-06-02 7:00:00'

SELECT Datediff(minute, @StartTime,  @EndTime )--480
```

`SP` should be like

```
Create Procedure usp_MinuteDiff(@StartTime DateTime,@EndTime DateTime)
as
Begin
 SELECT Datediff(Minute,@StartTime,@EndTime) 
End
```

Comment: It is giving me negative integer if start time is 23 to 7. for that what to do? It is like shift time. for an example :  23 on 1st june to 7oclock morning on 2nd june.

Comment: @user3601602 - I didn't get negative value check the first query in my answer

Comment: it will come 960.. but there should be 480 minutes only for 23 to 7.

Comment: @user3601602 - updated check now

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME='2014-06-23 23:00:00'
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME = '2014-06-24 07:00:00'

SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @STARTDATE,@ENDDATE)
```

In the datediff function the datepart specifies what data needs to be extracted, it takes the hours and calculates the difference

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer, not just a code

Comment: 2016-10-23 20:44:11.000 and 2016-10-22 20:44:11.000 these dates are not giving output. it is giving me output as NULL.

Comment: Are you using Sql or msql. Cause for the same data what youhave given have got the time difference as 0

Answer (score 0):

DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() as date) as datetime) + CAST(@StartTime as datetime),
      CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, (CASE WHEN @StartTime > @EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), GETDATE()) as date) as datetime) + CAST(@EndTime as datetime))..

This is the short and sweet answer.